# Check if page url exists (fast way - 1mio sites)

Tags: php, parsing, file-get-contents

I have a list of Alexa top 1 million. I want to check which of those 1 million sites are sites that have page www.domain.com/pageNameUrl.
I tried

```
foreach($sites as $site){    
  $file_headers = @get_headers($site);
  if(strpos($file_headers[0],"200 OK") !== false) {
    $exists = true;
    //save site name code...
  } else {
    $exists = false;
  }
}
```

But this code takes too much time. It would take 1 month or even more to go through all sites. Is there any other faster method?

Comment: What is configuration of the server where you run this? Maybe you should consider sunning it in a cloud. If you run it on your own machine it is obvious that the script is running slow.

Comment: you really need to think about using another language that is capable of threading. PHP is not a good use here. You can increase the speed by doing a lot of checks in parallel

Comment: seems like a good candidate for asynchronous requests

Comment: consider doing this asynchronically with Node.js

Answer (score 0):

I think php is not the right candidate for that job. You might thinking about something like nodeJs that is highly suitable for asynchronous jobs. Have a look at this (example taken from https://npmjs.org/package/crawler)

```
var Crawler = require("crawler").Crawler;

var c = new Crawler({
    // here you can define, how many pages you want to do in parallel
    "maxConnections":10,

    // This will be called for each crawled page
    "callback":function(error,result,$) {
        // mark this page as available or not based on the reponse
        console.log(result.statusCode);
    }
});

// Queue all your urls in a loop, they all will be push asynchronously to the crawler job
c.queue("http://www.google.de");
c.queue("http://www.amazon.de");
c.queue("http://www.facebook.de");
```